# SQL Update behaves weirdly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I am facing a weird behavior when updating sql database from php. I have a table in the database that I am trying to update with a modal. The table is simple containing three columns only. I have a button in my page that triggers a modal.The button is the following:

```
<a href="#update<?php echo $id;?>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle = "modal" data-target="#update<?php echo $id;?>"></i> Edit</a>
```

The $id is taken within a loop that the button is contained. So the modal is triggered and the modal code is the following:

```
<div id = "update<?php echo $id;?>" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                     <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                      <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                          </button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Edit Project Details</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         <form method = "POST" action = "update_project.php"> 
                           <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
                                <label>Project name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name = "name" class="form-control" value = "<?php echo $row['project_name'];?>">
                                    <br/>                               
                                <label>Status</label>
                                <select name = "status" class = "form-control">
                                    <option value = "Active">Active</option>
                                    <option value = "Inactive">Inactive</option>                            
                                </select>
                                    <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button  name = "update" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Everything is showing correctly in there all the values are correct. When i click on save changes the update_project.php is called that contains the following code:

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');

     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $project_name = $_POST['name'];
     $status = $_POST['status'];


         mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE project SET project_name='$project_name', project_status='$status' where project_id='$id'")
     or die(mysqli_error($con)); 


echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully updated project details!');</script>";
        echo "<script>document.location='project.php'</script>";
```

This is where my problem starts. I don not get any error there but the database is not updated. The weirder part is that only the last entry of the table is changed successfully, and when for example I set the last entry as inactive, it is changed and when I change another entry of the table it does not and it reverts the last entry back to active.

I have used the same code in other pages same parameters and it works fine but here it does not. What can be wrong? Why is updates the values so unexpectedly?

I have used several codes I run through the site to report any errors but none returned any error!

As an update Instead of using `<?php echo $id;?>` I replaced it with `<?php echo $row['project_id'];?>` with no luck. The whole code where the button is:

```
<?php   
include 'dbcon.php';

$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from project ORDER BY project_id ASC")or die(mysqli_error($con));
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$id=$row['project_id'];
$total=0;
$query1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM budget WHERE project_id='$id'");
while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
$total=$total+$row1['amount'];}
?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row['project_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $total;?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['project_status'];?></td>
    <td style="width:300px">
    <a href="#update<?php echo $row['project_id'];?>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle = "modal" data-target="#update<?php echo $row['project_id'];?>"><i class = "fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
 &nbsp;
<a href="budget.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-target="budget.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><i class = "fa fa-pencil"></i> Budget Category</a></td>
                                </tr>

<?php include 'update_project_modal.php';?>
    <?php }?>
```

After some debugging I did i have concluded that the $id value is passed to the modal correctly (I echod it in the modal title and the value matches in the database). The problem is in the update_project.php. There the $id value changes to the last enrty of the database for some reason. I echoed it to the message and it is the last entry... It seems that the $id does not pass from the modal to the update_project.php page...

Comment: is project_id really a string type in the database? `project_id='$id'` - you surrounded it with quotes

Comment: no it is an auto_increment int type... you mean in the UPDATE right? I tryed it without quotes no difference..

Comment: did you check what the value of $id actually is when you run the query?

Comment: The $id is a value from the project_id  column. It is correct because i am using it in another button in order to open another php page that adds further details to the project that is identified by the $id. '<a href="budget.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-target="budget.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"> Budget Category</a></td>'. In the next page I succesfully get the id to process the table and retrieve specific values..

Comment: No I mean check that the value of $_POST["id"] is correct, the one which gets passed into the query. The value you placed into some other random links is only tangentially relevant. Check the code which is actually running, the bit where the problem is. Don't just claim it's right because it's right somewhere else. If you're saying it updates the wrong row, then there's a good chance it's because your ID is wrong!! Another good thing would be to var_dump() your SQL just before you execute it, so you can see exactly what query is being run.

Comment: P.S. An important extra note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Well thats the weird part... when i choose the last entry to modify it, it modifies that one correctly. But when I choose an entry that is not the last one, it does not affect it at all, but also it changes the last entry to Active... Ofcourse when i add a new row, the new row is changed but the the previous one not. I dont know if I am explaining it right... I can modify whichever the last entry is, but not any other, plus when i modify any other the changes are not stored and the last entry's status (only the status not the name) is affected and gets back to active. Sorry if I was offensive.

Comment: Not at all offensive, no. Your description of the problem is fine, but it's based purely on observation, without any data. What I'm trying to get you to do is to get some debugging data which might lead us towards the solution. So, start dumping your SQL queries as I mentioned above. When you come to one which causes the strange behaviour, see if the query values are what you intended/expected them to be

Comment: Well you are right it is not working as I though... Instead of using $id=$_POST['id'] is set the id manually to a value that represents a project_id in the database. How it behaves is that it does not alter to the value I set, but replaces them with the values of the last entry... to the line i manually set as $id.. Considering to the injection attacks I have to check it... I was not aware of it... Thanks!